# Python 3: Read file, put it into list, then draw using turtle

Tags: python-3.x

I have a datafile.txt file with the following contents:

```
sand, 0
5,-5
10, 0
0, -15

river, 20
-500, 500
-460, -140
-300, -140
```

My aim is to read the file make it into a list then find the x and y coordinates. The coordinates are separated by the comma as the file shows

The file should be split into x and y coordinates

I have started as follows:

```
f = open("datafile.txt", "r")
fNew = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if len(line.strip())]
```

but when I pass it through
to find the label I used

```
label = fNew[0]
```

then for coordinates I used,

```
block = []
for coord in fNew[1:]:
     block.append(coord)
t= block[0]
turtle.setpos(t[0],t[1])
```

I'm trying to pass the file to turtle to draw an image of what I want but I ran into an error

```
builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: You mention that the line needs to be split by the comma, but at no point do you `split(',')`. You don't convert the coords to numbers. I suggest you create a function that takes a filename and returns a dictionary e.g. `{"river": {"whatever": 20, "coords": [(-500, 500), ...]}, ...}`, then you can test this separately from making the turtle go.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can provide in form of an answer how you could accomplish this

Comment: I am not going to write your code for you; you should at least make an effort to implement this yourself